# How to set an inactive object active in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a restart button in unity to restart the game, but the problem is that the button won't appear again after I have hidden it during the game.

Here is the code of the button:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class restartButtonScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player; 
    public Button restartButton;
    public GameObject restartButtonObject;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Player.GetComponent<playerScript>().playerEliminated == true)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
            
        }
        else if (Player.GetComponent<playerScript>().playerEliminated == false)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If Game Object is inactive, its update won't be called, that's why you aren't seeing your button appear.

Turn off buttons graphics instead of disabling whole gameObject.

Alternatively you can can create an empty parent to your button, attach restartButtonScript to it, and turn off just child gameObject with button. gameObject with script will be active, so its update will be running as well.

Also, you could make it active from another script, but that's not needed there.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm relatively new to Unity, so how do you turn off the graphics of a button?

Comment: You would need to disable buttons image component. Either create a field: Image buttonImage and assign its value in inspector or use GetComponent<Image>() in your button script. Then set image's enabled value to false: buttonImage.enabled = false;

Comment: Thanks man, it finally worked!

Comment: note that only turning of the graphics of a button is potentially not enough for actually preventing that button from being clicked ;) The better solution would be: Let some other object which does not deactivate itself control the button active state

Comment: True, button.interactable should be then set to false as well. I personally use alternative solution I provided which is to use empty parent that will control the button's state